# @keyframes transform: rotate() not working in Chorme, Safari

Tags: rotation, sass, compass

This code is working fine in firefox, but not on chrome or safari - it's just a simple rotating image...

```
img.spinner
    z-index: -1000
    margin: 0
    padding: 0
    width: 205px
    position: relative
    top: -315px
    left: -2px
    &:hover, &:active, &:focus
      outline: 0
      a
        outline: 0
    animation-play-state: running
    animation: spin 12s linear infinite

@keyframes spin
  from
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  to
    transform: rotate(360deg)
@-moz-keyframes spin
  from
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg)
  to
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg)
@-ms-keyframes spin
  from
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg)
  to
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg)
@-o-keyframes spin
  from
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg)
  to
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg)
@-webkit-keyframes spin
  from
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg)
  to
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg)
```

It's just a simple rotation, I'm using compass and sass, but the +keyframes mixin does not include some of the browser prefixes, so I've written it all out by hand >.< and It's still not working in Chrome and Safari.

Comment: If the problem is not related to the creation of the CSS file, you should be asking a pure CSS question instead and reduce this to the **smallest amount of code necessary** to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is really old, but in case anyone ends up here with this problem, it will most likely be fixed by replacing "to/from" with "0%/100%" I had this same problem and found that safari in particular did not like the to and from designation. Changing to a 0% and 100% fixed the problem without any further changes.